# navigationController sub-menu

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller, submenu

I have a navigationController with a back button on the left, pagination numbers in the middle, and two buttons within a segment on the left. The app displays sheet music and the next development is to add MP3.

Problem: adding an extra 'play' button on the navbar is a bit of a squeeze. Ideally we would have a submenu bar immediately below the navbar with all the MP3 controls. (play,stop,pause). You can remove the navBar to see music full screen - we would want the MP3 controls to do the same.

Any pointers to the best way of adding a submenu to a navigationController would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a UIToolBar at the bottom. It could always slide in and out if you think it takes up too much space to be there permanently.

Or change the buttons in the UINavigationController depending on the context